# Adding Dynamic Ads With Adsense

Tags: adsense

I have a page with about 50 blog posts per page. The content for each blog post is hidden with css and is shown when a user clicks on the blog post title. Is there a way to dynamically add adsense content to each blog post when a user clicks on the title? Is it allowed by Google?

I know I can add 50 ads to the page and have them hidden with css until the user clicks on the blog title but that would be very inefficient.

This is what Im trying to do:

**Example:**

http://jsfiddle.net/WZG2U/

**HTML:**

```
<div id="post1">
<h1>Blog Post 1</h1>
<p class="hidden">This is the content for blog post.</p>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
body {
    padding:30px;   
}

* {
    font-family:arial;
}

h1 {
    font-weight:bold;  
    cursor:pointer; 
    font-size:20px;
}

p.hidden {
    display:none;   
}

div.ad {
    float:right;
    background-color:red;
    height:100px;
    width:100px; 
    color:#ffffff;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:11px;
    text-align:center;
}
```

**Script:**

```
$("h1").click(function() {

    var thisid = $(this).parent().attr("id");

    if ($("div#"+thisid+ " p").hasClass("hidden")) {
        $("div#"+thisid+ " p.hidden").removeClass("hidden");

        // insert dymanic adsense ad
        $("div#"+thisid+ " p").before('<div class="ad">insert dynamic adsense ad here!</div>');
    } else {
        $("div#"+thisid+" p").addClass("hidden");
        $("div#"+thisid+" div.ad").remove();
    }

});
```

Comment: So, you have what seems to be working code...are you running into a problem? What is it you are asking?

Comment: My question is .. Is there a way to dynamically add adsense content to each blog post? Is it allowed by Google?

Comment: If you want to know if it's allowed by google, have a lawyer look over their ToS or send an email to google asking them. As for the dynamic content, the script you have already does that, with text, so try it with the adsense stuff and see if it works. Self experimentation is critical to the learning process.

Comment: I would have to ask WHY you want to do this. Is the user going to be clicking on Blog headlines so often that it makes sense to deliver all the content at once?

Answer (score 0):

It's up to the blog template if it can dynamically add ad code to the content to the page or not. Blogger has a monetize tab for using Adsense ads and it dynamically ads the code to the page at the page creation time. The page must be in plain html, meaning that you must have plain text and not scripted text or else the Adsense bot will have no text to walk to determine ad relevancy to the page and you could be banned for doing so. I mean you weren't trying to write a page entirely in ajax or something like that were you?